# Getting Linux prof samples even if my program is in sleep state?

Tags: perf

With a program without [sleep function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), [perf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) collects callgraph samples well.

```
void main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf(...);
    }
}
```

For example, more than 1,000 samples in a second.

I collected perf report with this:

```
sudo perf report -p <process_id> -g
```

However, when I do it with a program with sleep function, `perf` does not collect callgraph samples well: only a few samples in a second.

```
void main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf(...);
    }
}
```

I want to collect the callgraph samples even if my program is in sleep state aka. device time. In Windows with [VSPerf](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/visualstudio/profiling/vsperf?view=vs-2015), callgraph with sleep state is also collected well.

Collecting callgraph for sleep state is needed for finding performance bottleneck not only in CPU time but also in device time (e.g. accessing database).

I guess there may be a `perf` option for collecting samples even if my program is in sleep state, because not only I but also many other programmers may want it.

How can I get the prof samples even if my program is in sleep state?

---

After posting this question, we found that `perf -c 1` captures about 10 samples in a second. Without `-c 1`, perf captured 0.3 samples per second. 10 samples per second is much better for now, but it is still much less than 1000 samples per second.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Related blogpost by Gregg: Off-CPU analysis http://www.brendangregg.com/offcpuanalysis.html (and with flamegraphs too http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/offcpuflamegraphs.html). His solution is not as easy as single perf command, but it is about the profiling "sleeping" and blocked programs. Earlier 2015 solution with perf and higher overhead tracing on sched_* probes http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-02-26/linux-perf-off-cpu-flame-graph.html

Answer (score 2):

CPU samples while your process is in the sleep state are mostly useless, but you could emulate this behavior by using an event that records the begin and end of the sleep syscall (capturing the stacks), and then just add the the "sleep stacks" yourself in "post processing" by duplicating the entry stack a number of times consistent with the duration of each sleep.

After all, the stack isn't going to change.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a profiling target, `perf` will only account for events that were generated by said target. Quite naturally, a `sleep`'ing target doesn't generate many performance events.

If you would like to see other processes (like a database?) in your callgraph reports, try system-wide sampling:

```
    -a, --all-cpus
       System-wide collection from all CPUs (default if no target is specified).
```

(from perf man page)

In addition, if you plan to spend a lot of time actually looking at the reports, there is a tool I cannot recommend you enough: [FlameGraphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html). This visualization may save you a great deal of effort.

Comment: Thank you. Still I have a question. Does system-wide sampling collect the sample of my program who is in sleep state? If it doesn't, how can I deduct my program is in sleep state from samples for other processes?

Comment: I tried -a option and it still collects sample of my program insufficiently.

Comment: 1) System-wide sampling collects everything, including your sleeping program; 2) That's because your program is sleeping == not doing much of anything.